# Tourist guides for Kohanim

Tags: product-recommendation, kohen-priest, travel, geography, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

I recently saw a [tourist guide for Kohanim](http://www.crcweb.org/kohain_guide_museums.php), published online by the Chicago Rabbinical Council, listing certain Chicago tourist sites that are, and are not, problematic for Kohanim.

Are there any other local Va'adim that publish such guides, at least in major cities?  I would think this could prove to be a very useful tool, at least potentially.

Comment: http://rabbikaganoff.com/archives/1734

Comment: Try http://www.hakohanim.org/ (not active right now).