# Issues of Tumah vis a vis non-Jewish human remains

Tags: gentiles, death, kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

I was once told that there's a crypt in the Old City of Jerusalem near one of the gates (I forget which one), which houses the remains of a well-regarded non-Jew (once again, I forget the exact details), but that this doesn't pose an issue of Ohel because Ohel doesn't apply to non-Jewish remains.

Having been a student at the time and certainly not an expert in Tumah/Tohorah, nor a Kohen, I took this as fact without questioning it, until such time as I could learn these laws (which I still have not; at least not significantly more than before).

However, as I mentioned in [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31319/5), the Chicago Rabbinical Council has published an online Chicago tourism guide for Kohanim.  This seems irrelevant, if not silly, if the remains are not Jewish - and many of the issues of concern seem to be related to remains that are  almost certainly not Jewish (Egyptian mummies and the like).

So now I'm wondering if Ohel with non-Jewish remains actually *does* pose a problem for Kohanim.

More broadly, what Tumah issues do and don't apply to non-Jewish remains?

Comment: It's just inside Shaar Yafo and "alleged" to be the architect of the walls under Sulaman.

Comment: מועדים לשמחה. According to Tosafos (Y'vamos 61a, s.v. *Mimaga*), there is a machlokes between R' Shimon and the Chachamim, and we follow the sages who say they are מטמאין באהל. The Rambam (Shu"t 145) disagrees and holds that the Chachamim agree with R' Shimon that non-Jewish remains do not transmit *tum'ah* via *ohel*. Beit Yosef (YD 372:2; see also Sh"A, ibid.) discusses opinions of the rishonim on this and inclines toward the stringent view.

Comment: @Fred That's an answer. I was about to post "There is a good article [here](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?cat=626&id=18344&q=). Quote:
DO THE REMAINS OF A NON-JEW CONVEY TUMAS MEIS? The remains of a
non-Jew convey tumas meis if they are touched or carried. Although all
agree that the halacha is that the remains of a non-Jew convey tumah
through touching and carrying, there is a dispute as to whether the
remains of a non-Jew convey tumas ohel. The Shulchan Aruch rules that
it is proper to be stringent (Yoreh Deah 372:2)."

Comment: @Fred Good summary. Rav Moshe (can't find where) explains the words of _Shulchan Aruch_ more leniently.

Comment: Double AA, @Fred, et al, thank you. Would someone care to write up a full answer?

Comment: You are thinking of the Jaffa gate. The graves are those of the architects in charge of building the walls for Suleiman the Magnificant. There are three opinions: Suleiman had them buried their for their honor, he had them executed because they forgot to wall in David's Tomb, or he executed them because they went over budget and he didn't want to pay them.

Comment: @WAF Are you thinking of IM YD 2:166?

Comment: In regard to a different question http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=2556 says "There is no halacha of tuma'at ohel with a non Jewish body or cadaver." In any case there is also the possibility that the sealed case **may** prevent the spread of tumah into the room depending the space around the body inside the case..

Comment: I don't understand what the Jaffa-Gates-Tombs have to do with this, as they are under the open sky, behind a fence. The a tree growing above it is tall and thin and doesn't hover over the sidewalk (or the graves.) See it here http://tinyurl.com/lq5u3hk at Google maps.

Answer (score 5):

There is a good article [here](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?cat=626&id=18344&q=).

> DO THE REMAINS OF A NON-JEW CONVEY TUMAS MEIS?
>
> The remains of a non-Jew convey tumas meis if they are touched or
>   carried. Although all agree that the halacha is that the remains of a
>   non-Jew convey tumah through touching and carrying, there is a dispute
>   as to whether the remains of a non-Jew convey tumas ohel. The Shulchan
>   Aruch rules that it is proper to be stringent (Yoreh Deah 372:2).