# Are kohanim prohibited from University College London?

Tags: kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

Maybe a strange question, but the mummified remains of the British philosopher Jeremy Bentham are on display in a glass case at UCL.
See http://golondon.about.com/od/londonforfree/p/jeremybentham.htm

A related question: [Issues of Tumah vis a vis non-Jewish human remains](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31320)

Comment: This does not answer your question directly but UCL does have the Institute of Hebrew and Judaic Studies. I would suggest contacting them directly. They may have the answer you are seeking:  http://www.ucl.ac.uk/hebrew-jewish/contact-us

Comment: This link claims that UCL was one of three universities that explored DNA testing to confirm Kohanim ancestry. I assume Kohen's came on campus to partake in the studies.    http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/762109/jewish/Raise-Your-Hand-If-Youre-A-Kohen.htm