# Kohen Entering the Taj Mahal

Tags: death, kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

Can a kohen enter the Taj Mahal? When visiting India is a kohen allowed to enter even certain parts of the Taj Mahal? The tombs themselves are of non-Jews, of course, and they are buried beneath the earth.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taj_Mahal) most of the area is a memorial and not a tomb. You would first need to identify the tomb area and the mosque before considering what halachos apply. `The tomb is the centrepiece of a 17-hectare (42-acre)[5] complex, which includes a mosque and a guest house, and is set in formal gardens bounded on three sides by a crenellated wall.` Even the tomb area may have only a small section that would be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is taken from a different question ([Issues of Tumah vis a vis non-Jewish human remains](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31320/issues-of-tumah-vis-a-vis-non-jewish-human-remains))

Original source [DO THE REMAINS OF A NON-JEW CONVEY TUMAT MET?](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=6412)

> The remains of a non-Jew convey tumas meis if they are touched or
>   carried. Although all agree that the halacha is that the remains of a
>   non-Jew convey tumah through touching and carrying, there is a dispute
>   as to whether the remains of a non-Jew convey tumas ohel. The Shulchan
>   Aruch rules that it is proper to be stringent (Yoreh Deah 372:2).

Therefore it seems as though it is proper (according to the Shulchan Aruch) for a Kohen to be stringent and avoid the Taj Mahal as it represents an "ohel" for a corpse. As always, one should consult their LOR.